# Serialize exception when using remoting in .net

Tags: .net, serialization, .net-remoting

I am trying to use .net remoting to access an object on a remote PC.

The object has a function called `bool SetBitmap(System.drawing.Bitmap bitmap)`. Whenever a client calls this function the server should pass the bitmap to an unmanaged dll function called `bool Save(void* data, int size)`. However before I do this I copy the managed bitmap into unmanaged memory:

```
bool SetBitmap(System.drawing.Bitmap bitmap)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData = m_bitmap.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    bool result = Save(bmpData.Scan0, bitmap.Height * bitmap.Width * 3);

    bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    return result;
}
```

However when I call this function, I get an exception on the **client** side.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type '
System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData' in Assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable
```

I guess it has to do with the remoting, but why does my client care that a local variable on an object on the server is not serializable? Or is my assumption that the object only lives on the server pc wrong? What I want is my client to call some interface, let the magic happen on the server and then wait for the server to give it back a result.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?